# How is the page generating pop unders with no JavaScript code?

Tags: firefox, javascript, popups

I have JavaScript blocked on my browser (Firefox) using [NoScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NoScript), nevertheless I see "pop unders" on some web pages, for example, the [LA Times](http://www.latimes.com/#nt=mastheadnavbar). By a "pop under" I mean an animated box that appears at the bottom of the screen.

How is this happening with no JavaScript code?

Comment: What does it look like? I don't see anything animated there.

Comment: `.trb_bnn{position:fixed;bottom:0;right:0;width:100%;background-color:#294F70;z-index:10023;display:table;-webkit-font-smoothing:antialiased;-moz-osx-font-smoothing:grayscale}[data-bnn-closed] .trb_bn`

Comment: Hmm, so it is some kind of CSS thing. Maybe I should disable CSS.

Comment: FYI, I use YesScript which does block the blue pop-up at the lower left on the LA Times site when the domain is blacklisted and refreshed. So the CSS styles something that is loaded via javascript.